# formula, if cell A2 = "text", copy(drag down formula) form B1 to B2

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

As written in the title,

I am working on Google Form to list down the visitor entry to my office.
The visitor enters the form and a response is created in google sheets. 
However, we want to keep a track on his visit duration and I managed to create a count down timer in the spreadsheet. 
I created the formula for the timer for the previous responses, but when a new response is the created, a whole new row is created and the cell that was supposed to contain the formula is blank.

Is it possible to drag down the count down formula from the previous responses to create a new one for new response?
Say if

```
A2= "Visitor entered", B2 should copy the formula from B1.
```

Comment: Better you post the sample data & the Formula you have used for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you could pre-populate the cells anyway just ready for the data, such as using iferror():

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISTEXT(A2),"Yes","No"),"Blank")
```

Edit:
Now tested and working, the iferror makes the cell blank until there is data to test...